# Do not show install option for Connected Apps

Tags: connected-apps

I am a newbie in SalesForce, so this question might seem silly to some.

I am working on OAuth of Salesforce and it's complete actually and when user authorises the connected app, it gets showed in **Connected Apps OAuth Usage** section. But with the connected app, it shows two options:

- Install
- Block

From what's written on that page, I understood that *install* is for **To manage policies for connected apps developed outside your org** and *block* is **To prevents apps from running**.

I don't want *install* option to be seen here. I am not sure if it's possible though.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to remove *install* option for the connected app?
2. And what this install and block really mean?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean `Salesforce`? Here are the details around the install/block buttons - http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_security_identity_control_oauth_app_policies.htm

Comment: Fixed typo. This link was really helpful. Thanks. Can you also tell me if I can remove the install option? Because I don't want some other Salesforce user to connect to my connected app and able to change the policies of my app.